# xvfbwrapper is not working

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.6

I want to run python selenium script without opening a browser. I have installed xvfbwrapper-0.1.3 on rhel, and edited my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver,selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb


class SeleTry(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
        try:
            vdisplay = Xvfb(width=1280, height=720)
            vdisplay.start()
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
         .....//rest of the code//
```

when ever i am trying to execute it, it is throwing an eeror:

```
 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: cannot open display: :1013\n'
```

As i am new to it, i am not getting what i am going wrong?

Comment: do you have an X server, xvfb, and Firefox all installed on that machine?